# Gathering data using twitter search API

Tags: python, mysql, twitter

So part of my university project is to collect data from twitter for processing (mainly using the natural language toolkit). I am supposed to collect random samplings for specific hashtags and saving them into a mySQL database.

I have been reading articles online and it seems like Python is rather popular for this kind of thing. However, I can't figure out how to practically do it. could anyone write some sample code that can be used to harvest this data? or point me in the right direction? I have been reading the twitter API documentation have have a somewhat ok idea of how it works.

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search for "python twitter api getting started" yields the following:

http://popdevelop.com/2010/07/an-example-on-how-to-use-oauth-and-python-to-connect-to-twitter/

http://code.google.com/p/tweepy/wiki/GettingStarted/

http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/get_started_with_the_twitter_api/

The Twitter docs also list quite a few [Python libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#python). [Tweepy](http://code.google.com/p/tweepy/) seems to be quite popular.